# How Can I setup the Json.Net serializer to behave in a custom way?

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, json.net, locale

When I serialize, all my dates will be as local times, in order to mantain 
the backward compatibility with legacy applications that read/write to the same database or perform server to server integration.
But I want to produce UTC (ISO Format) string for web api my consumers, since they can be anywhere in my country.
As I live in Brazil and this country has more than 1 timezone, I do have to deal with this locale mess.

When I deserialize, I want to convert a utc formatted string to local format, due to the backwards compatibilities.

Brazil (Brazilia Time) is at -03:00 offset, then:

When the web api consumer inputs: "...T18:00:00.000Z", on the web api side the `DateTime` time would need to become "15:00:00" in the local format.

When the web api outputs the very same "15:00:00" `DateTime`, the serializer should translate that time back to "...T18:00:00.000Z" in the utc format.

If possible, I would like an application-wide solution, IOW, I don't want to decorate every class or property with a custom JsonConverter

Can you advise me on that?

Comment: Add your own converter to the JsonSerializer's Converters list.

Comment: @Brannon, I guess I will not need this anymore, the DateTimeZoneHandling.Local does the trick. I was using an older version. Should I add an answer for future reference? Or is this problem too localized?

Comment: @Brannon In the newest version 7.0.1, the DateTimeZoneHandling.Local correctly reads 18:00Z to 15:00 in local date and correctly generates 15:00 to 15:00-03:00 when serializing. It is in the offset format but It works for my case

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound: Yes, please write up your solution as an answer for others that have this same question.

Comment: @SamAxe Done. What do you think, should I add more information?

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound: I would just add a line of how to configure `JsonConvert` to use `DateTimeZoneHandling.Local`.  Otherwise it looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you described is the behavior of `DateTimeZoneHandling.Local`, at least in the 7.0.1 version, which is the newest version at the time this question was answered.

There is actually a minor difference: When the `DateTime` is serialized, the `JSonConvert`er will produce the time in the offset format [`15:00-03:00`] instead of UTF format [`18:00Z`]. This is as expected, I believe (at least make sense to me), since the format in the SerializerSettings is `DateTimeZoneHandling.Local`, if it were `DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` it would produce `18:00Z`, as expected.

When the DateTime is deserialized, a value in UTC format such as `"2015-01-01T18:00:00.000Z"`, will correctly become the same as `new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0,  DateTimeKind.Local)`.

To configure the `JsonConvert` add the following code in the `Register()` method of the `WebApiConfig`:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var settings = config.Formatters.JSonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
    settings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
    settings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
}
```

Disclaimer: The tests results are from a -03:00 offset. (Brazilia Time)